# Unable to compile LKM for Android

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, linux-kernel

I have Ubuntu 12.04 as compilation evironment.

I also have the **Cyanogen mod kernel**'s source code (get from Github: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/cm-kernel)

I use **toolchain** from Android NDK r5c (for linux)

I have the following code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

asmlinkage ssize_t (*orig_open)(const char *pathname, int flags);

asmlinkage ssize_t hooked_open(const char *pathname, int flags) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "SYS_OPEN: %s\n", pathname);
    return orig_open(pathname, flags);
}

void **sys_call_table;

static int __init root_start(void) {
    sys_call_table= (void *) 0x0030084;

    orig_open = sys_call_table[__NR_open];
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = hooked_open;
    return 0;
}

static void __exit root_stop(void) {
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = &orig_open;
}

module_init(root_start);
module_exit(root_stop);
```

This is my **Makefile**:

```
obj-m += root.o

all:
    make -C CyanogenMod-cm-kernel-2a32a61/ M=$(PWD) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- modules
```

My steps to compile in **Terminal**:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/hongnhat/lkm/android-ndk-r5c/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin
cd CyanogenMod-cm-kernel-2a32a61
make oldconfig && make prepare
cd ..
make
```

The result is:

```
make -C CyanogenMod-cm-kernel-2a32a61/ M=/home/hongnhat/lkm ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/hongnhat/lkm/CyanogenMod-cm-kernel-2a32a61'

  WARNING: Symbol version dump /home/hongnhat/lkm/CyanogenMod-cm-kernel-2a32a61/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

  CC [M]  /home/hongnhat/lkm/root.o
as: unrecognized option '-EL'
make[2]: *** [/home/hongnhat/lkm/root.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/hongnhat/lkm] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hongnhat/lkm/CyanogenMod-cm-kernel-2a32a61'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't know why it throws the **unrecognized option '-EL' error**.
Please help me address the problem, I have been pulling my hair out trying, I tried to use different **gcc** version (4.4.0, 4.4.3, 4.6) but no use.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling it with GCC from Sourcery Mentor. I have tried it before to compile Linux kernel for Android. Maybe it help.